# Can't call base class member functions because base class is templated

Tags: c++, .net, c++-cli

Is there some kind restrictions that if a base class is templated, we can't call its member functions in derived class? Wouldn't that violate the whole purpose of driving from it? Is there a solution?

Here is my example to demonstrate the problem:

These classes reside in class library.

```
namespace CLRLib {

    class A
    {
    public:

    };

    public ref class SimpleBase
    {
    public:

        void Hello()
        {
            cout << "SimpleBase::Hello() called" << endl;
        }

    };

    public ref class DerivedFromSimple : public SimpleBase
    {
    public:

        void Print()
        {
            cout << "Derived::Print called" << endl;
        }
    };


    template<class T>
    public ref class Base
    {
    public:
        T* m_Instance;

        void Hello()
        {
            cout << "Base::Hello() called" << endl;
        }

        T* GetInstance()
        {
            return m_Instance;
        }

    };

    public ref class Derived : public Base <A>
    {
    public:

        void Print()
        {
            cout << "Derived::Print called" << endl;
        }
    };
}
```

And this is the driver console application. Note, the problem does NOT occur if they both are in the same C++/CLI project!

```
int main(cli::array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Derived d;

    d.Print(); // yes
    //d.Hello(); // Doesn't compile, don't recognize the function.

    DerivedFromSimple d2;
    d2.Print();
    d2.Hello(); // Ok now

    return 0;
}
```

Again I can produce it *only* if the classes are in separate C++/CLI .NET library and the driver application is a separate C++/CLI console application. I *can't* call the base class methods in that configuration because they reside in different assemblies? And yes, no issues if they are in the same assembly! Quite strange.

The error message is:

> error C2039: 'Hello': is not a member of 'CLRLib::Derived'

**Update**

I did confirm it has to do with base class being a template class. I have updated the code above. When I derive from a simple base class (no template), the base class function is available and I can call but it's not accessible if base class use template.

**Update 2**

If I call the Hello() in the derived class member function, then I can also call it in the main program. But that doesn't solve the problem.

```
public ref class Derived : public Base <A>
{
public:

    void Print()
    {
        cout << "Derived::Print called" << endl;

        Hello();
    }
};
```

Comment: I don't think it's anything to do with the base being templated. You simply can't access a `protected`member outside of the scope of its own class and children.

Comment: I suggest you look up the meaning of `protected` before using it.

Comment: @George You are right. Let me update the question. Originally I was having issue with CLI but made an example in C++, will try to produce the problem with modified demo.

Comment: In your modified or new question, please include the error message from the compiler as well.

Comment: you could also add the error message here ;)

Comment: well, thats not what i was asking for! You now changed the question completely. It is no longer about c++ and the answer you got does not make any sense anymore. Usually I revert such edits when I see them immediately, however, I also don't want to throw away your effort. Now it is basically between you and the answerer. In the current state the answer could get downotes, because it appears to be offtopic, and that is only because you chnanged the question to be a different one

Comment: when you have a different question than the one you posted it is better to create a new question, hence I would suggest that you revert your edit to restore the old state and post the new question as a new question

Comment: Templates don't have external linkage, that doesn't get better in C++/CLI.  You need to use a header file, like you do in C++, or create generic types with the `generic<>` keyword.  The latter is very highly recommended, given that managed type identity includes the assembly it is defined it.

Comment: @HansPassant I tried the generics (which was new to me) but it doesn't seem to have syntax to pass a concrete object to base class in the derived. Additionally I found that if I call the base methd in the derived, then I can also call it from outside. Stil doesn't solve the problem though.  I updated post.

Comment: @HansPassant And I do need template solution because I want a member function to return pointer of the template class. I tried moving function implementation outside the class, but same problem exists.

Answer (score 1):

You have access issue:

You might change `protected` to `public`:

```
template<class T>
class Base
{
public:

    void Hello()
    {
        cout << "Base::Hello() called" << endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: Sorry I overlooked the protected part in hurry. I am going to modify my question.

Comment: Avoid to modify question which invalidate existing answer :-/ Probably better to ask another question.